# Stripe: Is it possible to convert a Payment Element object to a Card Element?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a complex integration with connected accounts and shared customers cards. A customer should register one time a card (saved on the platform account) and use it on any connected account.

Stripe tutorial available here: https://github.com/stripe-archive/developer-office-hours/tree/master/2020-12-15-clone-payment-method

I have a problem when adding a new card. Because customers can pay with a card **or** with any other payment methods available, I use `payment` element (browser side).

I would like to save the payment method **if** it is a card, and **before** payment is done. I would like to:

1. create new card payment method (`createPaymentMethod` browser side)
2. link this payment method with **platform** customer
3. create a shared payment method for the **connected** account
4. create a payment intent for the **connected** account, and with the **connected** customer (kind of a copy of the platform customer inside connected account)
5. confirm card payment with shared payment method and payment intent

The problem is I get an error at first step:

`Invalid value for createPaymentMethod: card was [payment] Element, which cannot be used to create card PaymentMethods`

Is it possible with `payment` element (browser side), or do I have to display two different forms depending on what customer wants to do (`card` element if customer wants to register a new card, and `payment` element if customer wants an other payment method OR not register the card)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `createPaymentMethod` function, you should create a SetupIntent and store the PaymentMethod on the Platform account [1]. Then you can follow this guide [2] to clone the customers as well as payment methods across connected accounts in order to re-use them.

The only catch here is that you mentioned that you only want to allow storing the Payment Method if its a `card` type. While you can set `setup_future_usage` parameter for only `card` payment methods when you create a PaymentIntent [3], this will setup the payment method on the account that creates the PaymentIntent (connected account in your case).

So a better approach here would be to ask your customers upfront about using cards vs another payment method and create SetupIntent or PaymentIntent accordingly.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-customers-across-accounts

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method_options-card-setup_future_usage

Comment: I was exploring SetupIntent right now, and I come to the same conclusion. The user first choose between "add new card" or "pay with other method". A setup intent will be used if add new card is chosen. When process is done, user cards list is refreshed. The new card can be selected and used. Thanks!